# Package for accessing Cassandra database in R

Tags: r, jdbc, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-jdbc

I have tried [RCassandra](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCassandra/) and [RJDBC](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/big-analytics-with-r-cassandra-and-hive) but unfortunately it seems that these bindings work only with the old Cassandra 1.x. Is there any binding for Cassandra 2.x in *R* language?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272452/unable-to-connect-cassandra-through-r) might help

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, the current version of [RJDBC](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/) works with Cassandra 2.X.

> Download latest release, with C* 2.x compatibility : cassandra-jdbc-2.1.1.jar

However there's one caveat that you have to also download the java dependencies and put them into your JAVA ClassPath (MacOS: /Library/Java/Extensions), otherwise you would encounter the painful `Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found` when initializing JDBC driver in R.

> Include the Cassandra JDBC dependencies in your classpath : download dependencies

As of the RCassandra package, right now it's still too primitive compared to RJDBC.